# SwiftUI TextField Binding to a simple Model (non-class sturct)

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I have a simple struct, that is decodable / codable and hashable.

```
public struct Field: Codable, Hashable {
    let key: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key
    }
}
```

In my SwiftUI, I'm creating an array, where I want to add and remove and Bind to the Struct values. But I am getting errors, that Struct is not Binding.

```
let decodableJSON = """
{
    "key": ""
}
"""
let settableInit: Field = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Field.self, from: decodableJSON.data(using: .utf8)!)

struct Test_view: View {
    
    @State
    var settableFields: [Field] = [settableInit]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(settableFields, id: \.key) { (settableField: Field) in 
             TextField("Key", text: settableField.key)
        }
```

But I get an error, that `settableField` is not Binding. I have tried adding the `settableInit` as an @ObservableObject to the main Swift View, but it still doesn't work.

Is there a way, to have the View bind to Struct properties, and have `TextField` change these properties? It feels like something so trivial, but for some reason undoable for me.

Thank you for any pointers!

Comment: since you are dealing with a JSON try an `ObservableObject` with a variable with a custom `{get set}` that read/writes to your JSON accordingly and at the end of `set` use `objectWillChange.send()` to refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Xcode13** you can use the new element binding syntax:

```
public struct Field: Codable, Hashable {
    var key: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key
    }
}

struct Demo: View {
    
    @State var settableFields: [Field] = [Field(key: "1"), Field(key: "2")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($settableFields, id: \.key) { $settableField in
            TextField("Key", text: $settableField.key)
        }
    }
}
```

In **earlier versions** of Xcode you could use the indices of the array:

```
struct Demo: View {
    
    @State var settableFields: [Field] = [Field(key: "1"), Field(key: "2")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(settableFields.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            TextField("Key", text: $settableFields[index].key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian, that did the trick for me! Legend